# How to apply do tactic to a sequence

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

Diving deep into `test_nostutter_1` excersize I found a way to solve it without repeat:

```
Example test_nostutter_1: nostutter [3;1;4;1;5;6].
Proof.
  constructor 3.
  (* This will apply the tactics to the 2-nd subgoal *)
  2: {apply eqb_neq. auto. }
  constructor 3.
  2: {apply eqb_neq. auto. }
  constructor 3.
  2: {apply eqb_neq. auto. }
  constructor 3.
  2: {apply eqb_neq. auto. }
  constructor 2.
Qed.
```

I decided to play more with it and in coq reference manual I found that there is [do tactical](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.do) that can loop a tactic several times.

```
do num expr
```

> expr is evaluated to v which must be a tactic value. This tactic value v is applied num times. Supposing num > 1, after the first
>   application of v, v is applied, at least once, to the generated
>   subgoals and so on. It fails if the application of v fails before the
>   num applications have been completed.

So I tried this:

```
do 4 constructor 3; 2: {apply eqb_neq. auto. }
```

But unfortunately it fails. Only this works:

```
do 1 constructor 3.
```

Is it possible to make it work using do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer

There are several issues in the line

```
do 4 constructor 3; 2: {apply eqb_neq. auto. }
```

First of all, you can't use the `2:` or `{}` after the chain operator `;`. The closest thing you can use is [sequence with local application](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#local-application-of-tactics) `tac; [tac1 | tac2]`. Since we want to do something on just the second branch, we can omit `tac1` here.

Also, you can't use periods inside a tactical. A period marks the end of a statement, but the whole `do` expression is a single statement. You should always use sequence operator `;` to chain several tactics.

Finally, `do n tac; tac` works like `(do n tac); tac`. You can wrap a tactic expression with parentheses, e.g. `do n (tac; tac)` to change the behavior.

So this one should work:

```
do 4 (constructor 3; [ | apply eqb_neq; auto ]).
```

---

#### Digression

We can simplify the line in several ways.

- `auto` can be given extra theorems to automate with. Any goal solvable with `apply eqb_neq; auto` is also solvable with `auto using eqb_neq`.

```
do 4 (constructor 3; [ | auto using eqb_neq ]).
```

- The `auto` tactic never fails, so it can be safely used on both branches.

```
do 4 (constructor 3; auto using eqb_neq).
```

- `repeat` repeats until something fails or there are no more subgoals. The following will repeat until the 3rd constructor is no longer applicable.

```
repeat (constructor 3; auto using eqb_neq).
```

- We can let Coq choose which constructor to apply. This can finish (or almost finish) the proof.

```
repeat (constructor; auto using eqb_neq).
```

- We can also make constructors of `nostutter` automated by `auto` using `Hint Constructors` command. Now we can `auto` the whole thing. (You can place the hint command right after your definition of `nostutter`, then you can `auto` it everywhere.)

```
Hint Constructors nostutter.
auto using eqb_neq.
(* if the above fails, the following increases the search depth so it should succeed. *)
auto 6 using eqb_neq.
```

- Actually, the theorem `eqb_neq` is already registered for `auto`. So we can just:

```
auto 6.
```

Comment: The theorem is proved by the authors of the book using this: `repeat constructor; apply eqb_neq; auto.` I just decided to look for alternative ways and play with different tactics and parameters, which is very useful for education.

Comment: Can you tell me, if I try: "constructor. [> | apply eqb_neq]." at the beginning of the theorem, it fails with message: "Error: Incorrect number of goals (expected 1 tactic, was given 2).". Why does this happen? I expected it to apply eqb_neq to the second subgoal.

Comment: @user4035 It's because the tactic is applied to only the first subgoal by default. I guess you can `all: [> | ... ].` though it's not very useful.